# Laravel higher order message unexpected result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-collection

I have a [higher order message](https://laravel-news.com/higher-order-messaging) in laravel. It looks like
this:

```
$category->scores->each->ratings->where('result.rating', '>=', 3)->count();
```

A `category` has `scores` a `score` has `ratings` and a `rating` has a `result`.

I want to get the total amount of ratings for every **category** `where >= 3`.

With the code I have right now the end result is always 0.

But when I loop over it like this:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->scores as $score)
        @foreach($score->ratings->where('result.rating', '>=', 3) as $rating)
            {{ $rating->result->result_nl }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

There are 3 rating results.

What is wrong with my higher order message?

Comment: The `each` proxy actually returns the scores collection (you can see why from the implementation in the [HigherOrderCollectionProxy](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php#L43-L48)). That's why the rest of the chain doesn't work as expected, because `$category->scores->each->ratings` returns the `$category->scores` collection and applying the `where` condition on that collection will most likely always return `0`. So basically the whole expression is equal to `$category->scores->where('result.rating', '>=', 3)->count();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few misunderstandings of Higher Order Functions in your question. In the documentation and in `Laravel` implementation they use method calls.

Here you are trying to do a `sum` on an each call, each does not return anything, but is a `Collection` method to be an alternative to `foreach`.

If you add the following function to the score model.

```
public function ratingsOverTree()
{
    return $this->ratings->where('result.rating', '>=', 3)->count();
}
```

You can use the `sum` method to add together the results, with the usage of the `ratingsOverTree()` method.

```
$category->scores->sum->ratingsOverTree();
```